# visual studio 2010 setup project containing the dlls for different architectures

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have a solution with a few c# projects, one c++ project and a setup project. Playing with the options it looks lik I want to include in my setup project a build of the c++ dll for each different architecture (x86, x64 .. ) that the solution could run on. How would I do this - playing around with the configuration manager in the setup project it likes like I can build one or the other and not both.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a configuration for each system you would like to build for.

If you want to have them all at the same time, add an empty project for each type you want built, and have them all include the same files and have different compiler settings.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've added the configuration but it still seems I can only select one as active at any time. I'd like the setup project to include all of them if possible.

Comment: @Richard, each individual project you add to the solution will have it's own build settings. You can select different settings for each project in the solution view window by right clicking on a project listed and going to properties.